# Java path isn't getting set in bash on Windows

Tags: bash, java, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Linux on Windows subsystem and when I try to run a code, i get the Unsupported major.minor version 52.0. I realize this is due to java version incompatibility.

So I set the JAVA_HOME and PATH as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin
```

But when i check the java version:

```
java -version
```

I get

> javac 1.7.0_121

How do i set the java path to the latest java version(1.8)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try export `PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:$PATH`